# Android Studio 1.3 CPU Monitor Memory Monitor Visible At The Same time

Tags: android-studio

Within Android Studio 6: Android tool window how to make both the CPU Monitor and the Memory Monitor visible at the same time as shown at the [the official tools site.](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview2available/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, finally:

By:

Click on the Widow that is floating around by CONTROL A.

Then mouse over and drag that windows Tab (the tab with the title of the used within Android Studio).

Drag back to the pace where the tabs in the tool window in Android Studio.

Hope that helps some one out.